# Swift: Add a xib into a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I would like to add a custom UIView. The class definition of my custom view is:

```
class UserCoinView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinAmount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinIcon: UILabel!

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let smartCoins = SmartShopperUtil.getSmartShopper().smartCoins

        if smartCoins != nil && smartCoins >= 0  {
            coinAmount.text = String(smartCoins!)
            coinView.backgroundColor = SmartShopperUtil.getSmartCoinBackgroundColor(SmartShopperUtil.getSmartShopper().smartCoins!)
        }

        userName.text = SmartShopperUtil.getSmartShopperNameWithFullName(SmartShopperUtil.getSmartShopper().name)
        coinIcon.text = AEVIcons.AEV_SMART_COIN
    }
}
```

I have added a View in the ViewController I want to add this view, and I have set the custom class of this view as UserCoinView. After that, I have made a connection to the ViewController, and in this ViewController I have no idea what to do in order to display my custom UIView.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is couple of ways you can do this.

**Add as subview programmatically.**

If you use autolayout, better place for that is `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

```
var myCustomView: UserCoinView? // declare variable inside your controller
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
  super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  if myCustomView == nil { // make it only once
    myCustomView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("UserCoinView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? UserCoinView
    myCustomView.frame = ...
    self.view.addSubview(myCustomView) // you can omit 'self' here
    // if your app support both Portrait and Landscape orientations 
    // you should add constraints here
  }
}
```

**Add as subview in InterfaceBuilder.**

You simply need put an empty view to you controller inside the storyboard, and assign your class for this view in Identity Inspector. After that, you can drag-n-drop outlets to your controller classes if you need one.

[image]

As for me, I prefer the second method because you don't need to hardcode frame / create constraints programmatically, just add autolayout.

Comment: Updated for Swift 5 : **myCustomView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MyCustomView**

Answer (score 3):

You can try This

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
   super.init(frame: frame)
    loadViewFromNib ()
 }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadViewFromNib ()
}

func loadViewFromNib() {

let view = UINib(nibName: "CreditCardExperyView", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

view.frame = bounds

view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]

self.addSubview(view);

}

   // Call subview 
   let creditCardView : CreditCardExperyView = CreditCardExperyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 280, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 280))

  selfView.addSubview(creditCardView)
```

Comment: This Works ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add it to a UIViewController's or UITableViewController's content view (or some other view in the view controller's view hierarchy) as a subview.

Answer (score 2):

in Latest swift -> for example:

```
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SectionHeaderView", owner: 
    self, options: nil)?.first as? SectionHeaderView 
    self.view.addSubview(headerView!)
    headerView?.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new myself, but this should work.

Adding:

```
viewControllerName.addSubview(userCoinView)
```

Removing:

```
userCoinView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use generic function. For project use make it global

```
struct GenericFunctions {
static func addXIB<T>(xibName: String) -> T? {
        return  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? T
    }
}
```

Use this generic function like:-

```
if let cell: StudentStatusTableViewCell = GenericFunctions.addXIB(xibName: "StudentStatusTableViewCell") {

            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
```

Benefit of generic is you can use this function for adding **View**, **Tableviewcell** and any other element. make sure you are using type in call like  **let cell: StudentStatusTableViewCell**  otherwise compiler won't infer the type.

Happy coding :)