# Programatically adding custom view to another view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit

I've created a custom view using a .xib file for the layout. I would like to programatically create and add this view as a subview to a different view.

Subview class:

```
class Subview: UIView {

@IBOutlet var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Subview", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about it, the only constructor currently expects an instance of NSCoder which I don't have.

I've tried to give it an additional initialiser:

```
init(title: String, text: String) {
    titleLabel.text = title
    textLabel.text = text
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

And then call it:

```
let v = Subview(title: dataSource[i].whatever, text: dataSource[i].bla)
```

But it fails when trying to unwrap the label outlets, which makes sense as the .xib hasn't been initialised.

I've already tried using a tableview and custom cells instead of programatically building the UI for the page, it doesn't really work because this is a detail page and I only have a single object as my data source instead of the array which the rowForIndexPath tableview delegate expects. I know I could write some mapper method to turn the object into an array of it's properties but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Because in your case only the class has been initialized not the outlets as nib initialization was not assigned, you can try `self = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Subview", owner: self, options: nil)?[0]`

Comment: look ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/33946855/4003548.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659714/loading-a-xib-file-to-a-uiview-swift/35666644#35666644 This should be helpfull

Comment: Thanks for the responses, when I try either solution I'm seeing this error when I try using Bundle.main.loadLibNamed: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key, which I think is an issue with the outlets. I should also note, I can add the xib to my storyboard with no problems at all, I may need to create more than one which is why I need to figure out how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Go to `Subview.xib` and make sure that the file owner is left empty.

[image]

Also, make sure that the class for your view is selected as `Subview`.

[image]

2) Get rid of the initializer, so:

```
class Subview: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Subview", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

should be:

```
class Subview: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!
}
```

3) Initialize you view this way:

```
let view = UINib(nibName: "Subview", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! Subview
```

You can also check out these.

http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

[How to initialise a UIView Class with a xib file in Swift, iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25513271/how-to-initialise-a-uiview-class-with-a-xib-file-in-swift-ios)

Good luck!

Comment: +1 but the only issue I found with this, is that the bounds aren't set this way and the custom view is not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle IBOutlets I suggest you use a UIViewController as the owner of the xib instead of a UIView (when creating a UIViewController from File menu there is the option to create also a xib)

Then you can instantiate it this way in the parent view

```
    var subviewController: SubviewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        subviewController = SubviewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        self.view.addSubview(subviewController!.view)

        //Remember to call the IBOutlets only after adding the view
        subviewController!.titleLabel.text = "This is the title" 

        subviewController!.view.frame = self.view.frame //Not suggested
        //Instead set constraints here
    }
```

Either way you have to set constraints or end using viewDidLayoutSubviews() as suggested in [Swift: Add a xib into a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945551/swift-add-a-xib-into-a-uiview/33946855#33946855)

Answer (score 0):

Custom subclasses can be tricky, particularly when using xib files. With the code you've shown, it's not clear where you're going wrong - but yeah, probably losing the Outlet connections.

Here's a working example - includes Obj-C and Swift versions, including using the custom classes within Interface Builder. Specifically for what you're trying to do, look at the Swift3/SW3LoadFromXIB example:

https://github.com/DonMag/IBDesignInspect